# How to update the parent entity specific field using python in odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I have a problem on updating the state of the parent table in hr.job table.

I inherit 'hr.job' table and i want to update the 'state' field

I have a table named: 'job_req_tbl' inherits 'hr_job'

Both have same field named 'state'

in my web_app screen there is a button named "Confirm" , and when the user click it I want 'hr_job' > 'state' value from 'open' to 'recruit'

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with following code:

```
@api.multi
def action_click(self):
    self.hr_job.state = 'recruit'
```